# Evaluating linear search execution speed

Tags: python, search, optimization

When I learned how to code someone told me that the "break" instruction was not elegant from an algorithmic perspective and it should not be used. However I've tried to compare the execution speed of two different versions of the linear search algorithm and the version with a for loop is always faster.

Any opinions?

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time
n = 100000;
x = np.arange(0,n)
random.shuffle(x)

k=30  # the number to search for

#--- OPTION 1: LINEAR SEARCH USING WHILE LOOP
start_time = time.time()
i=0
while (x[i]!=k) and (i<n-1):
    i+=1   
print(i)    
print("V1 --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

#--- OPTION 2: LINEAR SEARCH USING FOR LOOP w/ BREAK
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(0,n):
    if x[i]==k:
        break
print(i)
print("V2 --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Does Pyhon do 0-based or 1-based indexing? (your loops are not equivalent) Also, you shoud check the index **before** using it.

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected the range in the for loop. About the index, you say "i=0" before "for" ?

Comment: BTW: your usage of the `&` operator ... a bit is strange, Also: shortcicuit-evaluation could cause the `while()` version to step on an index-error.  And there is also the issue of cache-warming. Conclusion: performance should not be questioned until the program is correct.

Comment: Some additional tweaks :) were included.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation it appears that the `&` does not short-cicuit in Python; while `and` does. So it seems like the order of evaluation is not guaranteed in your case.

Comment: I've tested the script with k=-1 and both loops ended in 99999 with no errors. In these cases there should be a missing "if", after the loops, to detect if the last element of the range is "the one" or if it is a "not found" situation. Since it is common to both option, it will not represent a difference in execution time.

Comment: Did you try with `n=1` ?  it will fail even faster!1!!!1

Comment: My guess is that you took their statement way out of context. That they said that about some specific code you showed them and that they didn't mean you should *never* use `break`.

Comment: @wildplasser with n=1 it runs with no problems

Comment: So, you read the "short-circuit" link. But you dont understand it. You changed the bitwise AND for a logical and, but you did still do not understand the short-circuit?

Comment: @wildplasser I understand that you are really doing your biggest effort to help but probably not the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't listen to "someone".  Everyone uses break statements.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with using them.  The can make your code both easier to understand and simpler:  a win-win as far as I'm concerned.